# Imparting expert knowledge for predicting branch statements in C# or C++

Tags: c#, c++

I know some CPUs attempt to predict branch statements when deciding what code to pre-fetch, I was wondering if there was a way to help or hard code those branch predictions in C# (or C++). An example would be an error checking if statement which I know will return false 99.9999999% of the time, I would like to tell the CPU to always expect that branch to never happen for pre-fetching purposes.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you feel this is necessary?

Comment: today in micro-optimization gone wild we present..

Comment: @chibacity some times it could be very important and give some performance increase.
But most brand new CPUs has quite good branch predictors with a big history cache.

Comment: actually the JIT compiler can gather runtime profiling info that I would think would do this sort of optimization automatically anyway, or wouldn't it?

Comment: @BrokenGlass - surely it would be jitted the first time, then left alone...? No profiling the first time...

Comment: @Marc I thought if a particular piece of code is a "hotspot" the JITer could choose to optimize later based on profiling data? If so then asymptotically it's the same - I don't know much at all about the .NET JIT compiler so I might be completely off

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is no cross-platform solution to this problem.  I would expect that C# VM would do some sort of runtime analysis to optimize for these sorts of predictions, though I don't know this for a fact.

For C/C++, there are a few platform-specific tools to help optimize this.  You can usually find profile-guided optimizers for the code.  I know for a fact that gcc and g++ support this, and that it can make a pretty big difference in the net program performance.  gcc also supports a compiler-specific extension called `__builtin_expect` that lets you hardcode in your assumptions about branch prediction:

```
if (__builtin_expect(x == 0, 0)) { // Unlikely to occur
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: This question describes how to do profile-guided optimizations with g++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365980/how-to-use-profile-guided-optimizations-in-g