# C performance measure

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, mingw, performancecounter

I'm looking for a measure performance tool for C (I'm using MinGW windows toolchain) that gives me some results like:

- Occupied memory by a variable;
- Cycles to run the program/a function;
- Spent time on a function.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Perftools is multi-platform: http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/

GCC has profiling as well: [How to use profile guided optimizations in g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365980/how-to-use-profile-guided-optimizations-in-g)

Answer (score 0):

You can use gprof with is shipped with GCC. Here are [some](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-gnuprof.html?ca=dgr-lnxw04GNUProfiler) [examples](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof_toc.html).

You'll find more about that in the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/). Just remember that you must use the `-pg` option for both compilation **and** link.

However, I got that working, but only on small software. On the bigger one I work on, I only got empty timing, and couldn't find the cause of that. But maybe you won't have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Usually when gprof does not give you results it is because it is a multithread application. gprof does not support this kind of apps.