# Clang or GCC equivalent of _PGOPTI_Prof_Dump_All() from ICC

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, clang

Intel C(++) Compiler has very useful functions to help with profile guided optimisation.

```
_PGOPTI_Prof_Reset_All();
/* code */
_PGOPTI_Prof_Dump_All();
```

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/512800

This is particularly useful for profiling shared libraries which one would use with `ctypes` in Python.

I've been trying to figure out if either Clang or GCC have similar functionality – apparently not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that both have an internal and not properly documented function named `__gcov_flush` which does this. It is only explained in the [source](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/bc587267bd85c2b30d8c0e8448ee6a5739271516/libgcc/libgcov-interface.c#L78%20source).

> /* Called before fork or exec - **write out profile information
>   gathered so    far and reset it to zero**.  This avoids duplication or
>   loss of the    profile information gathered so far.  */

It's not quite as convenient as the Intel equivalent though and requires some gymnastics to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Profile guided optimization works differently in gcc and it is enabled with compiler switches. [See this question for PGO with gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365980/how-to-use-profile-guided-optimizations-in-g).

PGO just recently arrived in clang and is only available starting at version 3.5. The [clang user manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#profile-guided-optimization) gives an overview of how to use it.