# How to inform GCC about hotspots(often executed) and coldspots(seldom executed) in the code?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

Let's say there's this code:

```
int foo() {
//code
}

int bar() {
//code
}
```

And if it's known for a fact that `foo` is called many times and `bar` is not called very much, how can the compiler be informed of this so that it optimises `foo` for speed and `bar` for size?

Answer (score 1):

The function attributes `hot` and `cold` can be used for this. Use the attribute `hot` for functions which will be executed more(in this case, `foo`) and `cold` for functions which won't be executed often(in this case, `bar`).

Like this:

```
__attribute__ ((hot)) int foo() {
//Will be optimised for speed.
}

__attribute__ ((cold)) int bar() {
//Will be optimised for size.
}
```

More about this and other extensions in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes. These attributes can be used in labels as well.

A better option is to use profile guided optimisation: [How to use profile guided optimizations in g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365980/how-to-use-profile-guided-optimizations-in-g). It will take more time as the program needs to be compiled twice and tested once. So, the above method using `hot` and `cold` attributes is better for developing and profile guided optimisation is better for releases. If profile guided optimisation is used, then the attributes `hot` and `cold` will be ignored.