# Reduce the cost of abstraction layer by inlining

Tags: c++, interface, abstraction

In my project I have some abstraction layers like this one:

```
 Vector3 normalizeVector(Vector3 v);

 Vector3 vectorMultiplyMatrix(Vector3 v, Matrix3 m);
```

Which are simply "proxy" functions to platform specific math libraries like DirectXMath.

My question is how can I reduce the cost of these layers? By making all these functions inline will the cost of calling them instead of directly calling the platform specific ones be completely eliminated?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cost of adding a new abstraction level (proxy, facade, etc.) in the meaning of bundling a bunch of function calls within another one is negligible. The way you pass the data to them might cause you troubles, especially while using complex objects, containers, etc.

```
Vector3 normalizeVector(Vector3 v);
```

creates a copy of passed `Vector3` object upon each call. If you face performance issues, then avoid copy being created by changing passing by value to passing by `const` reference:

```
Vector3 normalizeVector(const Vector3& v);
```

This new prototype of this function expresses: *"I need a reference to an existing valid `Vector3` object that I will use but not change"*.

Just don't optimize your code unless you really face performance issues. *Premature optimization* has been always evil and always will.

Comment: I already pass the arguments by reference, the code in the question is just code that I wrote as an example. Thanks anyway :) I'm more interested on the effects of inlining...

Answer (score 1):

Exposing the body of the function will give the compiler an *opportunity* to eliminate the function call through inlining.

Whether it will actually take it depends on its internal heuristics: inlining may enlarge the overall size of the generated code, making it less cache-friendly and eventually negating the benefit of eliminating the call.

There are special keywords (e.g. [__forceinline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88(v=vs.110).aspx) under VC++) that you could use to override the compiler's cost/benefit analysis, but compilers are more often right about these kinds of decisions than programmers are!

Using [profile-guided optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57553/533120) can help the compiler make better optimization decisions based on the actual usage pattern of the program, including which functions are "hot" enough to inline and which are "cold" and should be left alone.

---

One especially powerful technique to keep in mind is [template metaprogramming](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3743/A-gentle-introduction-to-Template-Metaprogramming). The idea is to push as much calculation to compile-time as possible.